# Внесение изменений в плагин YARPP

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Есть сайт, сделанный на *WordPress* с плагином *YARPP*. После каждой статьи, с помощью плагина *YARPP*, выводится небольшой блок с похожими статьями.

Пример:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать так, чтобы вместо последней статьи выводился какой нибудь рекламный баннер. Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день, опять.
Со вчерашнего дня ждал пока кто нибудь поможет решить возникшую задачу, но, как я понял, в связи с тем, что данный вопрос не особо интересен форумчанам, решил разобраться сам.
С помощью гугла и метода "тыка" определил какой из файлов плагина отвечает за вывод похожих статей, или формирование ссылок на эти статьи, не знаю как правильно. Так вот, этим файлом оказался файл template_thumbnails.php, который находится в папке includes. Вот кусок кода который отвечает за вывод:

```
$output .= '<h3>' . $thumbnails_heading . '</h3>' . "\n";

if (have_posts()) {
    $output .= '<div class="yarpp-thumbnails-horizontal">' . "\n";
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();

        $output .= "<a class='yarpp-thumbnail' href='" . get_permalink() . "' title='" . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . "'>" . "\n";

        $post_thumbnail_html = '';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            if ( $this->diagnostic_generate_thumbnails() )
                $this->ensure_resized_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), $dimensions );
            $post_thumbnail_html = get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $dimensions['size'] );
        }

        if ( trim($post_thumbnail_html) != '' )
            $output .= $post_thumbnail_html;
        else
            $output .= '<span class="yarpp-thumbnail-default"><img src="' . esc_url($thumbnails_default) . '"/></span>';

        $output .= '<span class="yarpp-thumbnail-title">' . get_the_title() . '</span>';
        $output .= '</a>' . "\n";

    }
    $output .= "</div>\n";
} else {
    $output .= $no_results;
}
```

Так вот, после двух часов издевательства над бедным плагином, используя великий и могучий метод "тыка", определил где должен быть код, который нужен мне и что из себя вообще он представляет.
Вот как в итоге выглядит код:

```
$output .= '<h3>' . $thumbnails_heading . '</h3>' . "\n";

if (have_posts()) {
    $output .= '<div class="yarpp-thumbnails-horizontal">' . "\n";
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();

        $output .= "<a class='yarpp-thumbnail' href='" . get_permalink() . "' title='" . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . "'>" . "\n";

        $post_thumbnail_html = '';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            if ( $this->diagnostic_generate_thumbnails() )
                $this->ensure_resized_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), $dimensions );
            $post_thumbnail_html = get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $dimensions['size'] );
        }

        if ( trim($post_thumbnail_html) != '' )
            $output .= $post_thumbnail_html;
        else
            $output .= '<span class="yarpp-thumbnail-default"><img src="' . esc_url($thumbnails_default) . '"/></span>';

        $output .= '<span class="yarpp-thumbnail-title">' . get_the_title() . '</span>';
        $output .= '</a>' . "\n";

    }

// ***

 if ( trim($post_thumbnail_html) != '' )
            //$output .= $post_thumbnail_html;

                          $output .= '<a title="Государственная поддержка ННО" alt="Государственная поддержка ННО" href="http://grants.oprf.ru/grants2014-1" target="_blank"><img  title="Государственная поддержка ННО" alt="Государственная поддержка ННО"  src="http://grants.oprf.ru/grants2014-1/files/links/grants_240-180.gif" style="width: 150px; height: 120px;" /></a>';
        else
            $output .= '<span class="yarpp-thumbnail-default"><img src="' . esc_url($thumbnails_default) . '"/></span>';

        //$output .= '<span class="yarpp-thumbnail-title">Пример поста4</span>';
        $output .= '</a>' . "\n";
// ***


    $output .= "</div>\n";
} else {
    $output .= $no_results;
}
```

Короче говоря, взял верхний if, привел в нужный мне вид и вставил после цикла. В итоге вот как выглядит блок похожих статей:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечно нужно немного подровнять и все такое, но думаю с помощью css это можно сделать.
Тема была о Внесение изменений в плагин YARPP, изменения я внес, осталось понять правильные ли они. Так что знатоки веб программирования пожалуйста зацените получившийся код, может надо что добавить, может что то вообще убрать. Спасибо.